# Sort negative values

Tags: unix, sorting, negative-number

I have a problem with sorting my sentence values ​​in descending order:
I typed this command in unix:

```
sort fileInput -t"(" -k2r >fileSort
```

Here's the input file:

```
comité de conciliation de décision du parlement européen et du (0.00098379)
les amendements CARD CARD CARD CARD CARD CARD et CARD (-0.00025165)
la protection des consommateurs sur la proposition de directive du (0.00077120)
```

and here's the output file:

```
comité de conciliation de décision du parlement européen et du (0.00098379)
les amendements CARD CARD CARD CARD CARD CARD et CARD (-0.00025165)
la protection des consommateurs sur la proposition de directive du (0.00077120)
```

The file is not well sorted
Any idea please?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-n` and `-g` options for numeric sort like this:

```
sort -t"(" -ngk2r
```

Comment: You may need another option (`-g` in GNU sort) to sort floating point numbers.

Comment: @user17241: Which flavor of Unix are you using? It is working on my Mac and Linux centOS6.

Comment: @anubhava x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I have `2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64` and it is working fine here. Are there only those lines in input or there are more?

Answer (score 0):

use -rk2 instead of -k2r, that is

```
sort fileInput -t"(" -k2r >fileSort
```